# SQL Server 2012 Bulk Insert from CSV into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, temp-tables

As the title says, I am attempting to insert a CSV into a temporary table. I am unfortunately encountering errors.

Here is the query:

```
USE DATABASE5000

CREATE TABLE #tempTable1
(
    ID INT,
    CD VARCHAR(50), 
    ESD DATETIME,
    EED DATETIME, 
    MiscDate DATETIME, 
    SQ SMALLINT
) 

BULK INSERT #tempTable1
FROM 'C:\Dir\Folder\BestFile.csv';
```

And here are the errors I get:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Any ideas? Thanks yall.

Comment: "An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file" - your file is "corrupt" - i.e. a comma in the wrong place, not enough fields, not consistent field delimiters. Something like that.

Comment: You didn't specified any `FIELDTERMINATOR`. The default is `tab`. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Squirrel is right. Also make sure the last line doesn’t have a terminator leaving you with an extra row which is blank

Comment: @Squirrel Thank you! Setting fieldterminator to "," did the trick. You'd think they'd include that in the "BULK INSERT from CSV" documentation. If you make this an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You didn't specified any `FIELDTERMINATOR`. The default value is actually `tab`. Please refer to [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

```
BULK INSERT #tempTable1
FROM 'C:\Dir\Folder\BestFile.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ','           -- add this
);
```

According to documentation, there is a `FORMAT = CSV`

```
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV')
```

You may try that. I did a quick test, there are some limitations it seems like does not support string with double quote in it

Comment: Thanks again! Just for the sake of documentation, (FORMAT = 'CSV') throws an error for me in SQL Server. Omitting this part worked fine.

Comment: `FIELDTERMINATOR` does not work for me at all. If I replace all the commas with tabs beforehand then it works. I don't have a clue why this is the case. Also, I only have good results with `ROWTERMINATOR` in hexadecimal format.

Comment: Answering my comment/rant above, using `DATAFILETYPE = 'char',` as one of the arguments solves the issue.

Comment: The question title specifically mentions SQL Server 2012.  FORMAT = 'CSV' apparently wasn't added until SQL Server 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#format--csv